# adding values with sGlide plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add values of three slider bars together. I have a function to add them but no matter where I call the function it breaks the page. Now the values of each slider is counting live but when i load the page i get a NaN for the value of total even if a slider starts at a position other than 0.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html><head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=560, user-scalable=0;">
```

```
<title>sGlide - working</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sGlide.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slider1').sGlide({
        'width': 85,
        'height': 60,
        'image': 'img/knob.png',
        //'startAt': 'slider3 o.value',
        'colorStart': '#3333FF',
        'colorEnd': '#000080',
        'buttons': true,
        drag: function(o){
        $('input[type=text][id="amount1"]').val(o.value);
    },
        onButton: function(o){
        $('input[type=text][id="amount1"]').val(o.value);
    }

    });

    $('#slider2').sGlide({
        'width': 85,
        'height': 60,
        'image': 'img/knob.png',
        //'startAt': 'slider3 o.value',
        'colorStart': '#360',
        'colorEnd': '#693',
        'buttons': true,
        drag: function(o){
        $('input[type=text][id="amount2"]').val(o.value);
    },
        onButton: function(o){
        $('input[type=text][id="amount2"]').val(o.value);
    }

    });

    $('#slider3').sGlide({
        'width': 85,
        'height': 60,
        'image': 'img/knob.png',
        'startAt': 40,
        'colorStart': '#CC99CC',
        'colorEnd': '#4C1A4C',
        'buttons': true,
        drag: function(o){
        $('input[type=text][id="amount3"]').val(o.value);
    },
        onButton: function(o){
        $('input[type=text][id="amount3"]').val(o.value);
    }

    });




function update() {
 $amount1 = $("#slider1").val(o.value);
 $amount2 = $("#slider2").val(o.value);
 $amount3 = $("#slider3").val(o.value);
 $total = $amount1 + $amount2 + $amount3;
 //$("#amount").val($amount1);
 //$("#amount2").val($amount2);
 //$("#amount3").val($amount3);
 $("#total").val($total);
}
});
 </script>

</head><body>

<div id="slider1" class="slider_bar"></div><input id="amount1" type="text" /><br /><br />
<div id="slider2" class="slider_bar"></div><input id="amount2" type="text" /><br /><br />

<div id="slider3" class="slider_bar"></div><input id="amount3" type="text" /><br /><br />

 <br />
 <h3>Total</h3>
 <input id="total" type="text" />


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not calling your update function anywhere in your code. If you want to update the total textbox when the bar is dragged, you need to call the function inside every drag event.

Also you are setting the value you get from the drag event parameter to the text fields but you are trying to get it from slider object. I haven't worked with sGlide but when I debugged the code, value of the sliders didn't return the value you expected so it will be better to get the values from text fields.

In the end your update function should be something like this.

```
function update() {
    $amount1 = $('input[type=text][id="amount1"]').val();
    $amount2 = $('input[type=text][id="amount2"]').val();
    $amount3 = $('input[type=text][id="amount3"]').val();
    $total = parseFloat($amount1) + parseFloat($amount2) + parseFloat($amount3);
    $("#total").val($total);
}
```

Also as I stated before you need to call this function in your drag events.

Hope this helps...